# Empty band list in NAIP data

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am using NAIP data for calculating NDVI. The band list is empty when I run the program
Here's my code

```
var naip =  ee.ImageCollection("USDA/NAIP/DOQQ")
.select(['R','G','B','N'])
.filterDate('2021-01-01','2021-02-01')
.mean(); 

var addNDVI = function (image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['N','R']).rename();
  return image.addBands(ndvi)
}
print(naip)
naip.map(addNDVI)
Map.addLayer(naip, {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['#edf8fb', '#ccece', '#99d8c9', '#66c2a4', '#2ca25f', '#006d2c']}, 'ndvi');
```

Empty band list on the console:
Image (0 bands)
type: Image
bands: []
Line 11: naip.map is not a function

Comment: Maybe you don't have a 4 band image?  Run gdalinfo or EXIFTools on the images and check the band name tag.

Answer (score 1):

Information related to 'USDA/NAIP/DOQQ' Image Collection in [this link](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/USDA_NAIP_DOQQ), reveals that availability is between 2002-06-15 and 2020-12-17. So, this explains your empty band list for your dates range .

Fixing your dates range, it is also necessary to filter by using a geometry for avoiding more than 5000 elements in data collection. I employed an arbitrary point (-80.74949, 39.45924) for this task. It was also necessary to use a new palette because the one in your code had not valid colors.

All modifications are reflected in following code lines.

```
var pt = ee.Geometry.Point(-80.74949, 39.45924);

var naip = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NAIP/DOQQ')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2017-01-01', '2018-12-31'))
                  .filterBounds(pt);

print(naip);

Map.centerObject(pt, 12);

function addNDVI (image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['N','R']).rename('ndvi');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
}

naip = naip.map(addNDVI);

var ndvi = naip.select('ndvi');

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["ndvi"],
                     "min":-0.3550,
                     "max":0.4545,
                     "palette":["faff12","f79706","ff2b08","130eff","066e0a"]};

Map.addLayer(ndvi, imageVisParam, 'ndvi');
```

After running above code in GEE code editor, I got result of following picture.

[image]